# How to create users and define their permissions in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, nosql

If you want to add authentication to a MongoDB database to allow only allowed users to access it with specific rights allowed to each. How to get started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Here is how one can create their first user and attach them to admin role.

While creating a user add the third argument as an array of role names. See the following done in shell:

```
sudo mongod --auth
```

In new terminal run the following:

```
mongo
use admin
db.createUser({user: "myname", pwd: "mypass", roles: ["userAdminAnyDatabase"]})
```

User then can log in with their credentials that we just registered with the following expression:

```
db.auth("myname", "mypass")
```

Alternatively ypu can use the following method to log in:

```
mongo -u myname -p mypass --authenticationDatabase admin
```

If you want to create a user to have access to just one particular database the follow this expression:
Go into the database

```
use mydb
```

Create user and assign a role

```
db.createUser({user: "yourname", pwd: "yourpass", roles: ["readWrite"]})
```

Now logout from first admin user

```
db.logout()
```

Login with the new user

```
mongo -u yourname -p yourpass --authenticationDatabase mydb
```

Get into the mydb database

```
use mydb
```

Then you can perform read and write operations on mydb database

```
db.mycollection.insertOne({name: "Vinit Khandelwal"})
```

#### Here is a bonus: Update user roles and database access

1. Logout and login with admin of admin database
2. Get into mydb database

Then run the following:

```
db.updateUser("mydb", {roles: ["readWrite", {role: "readWrite", db: "yourdb"}]})
```

This gives the user a `readWrite` access to `mydb` as well as to `yourdb` database

Comment: MongoDB allows the first user to be made without authentication from localhost only.